# Unable to import Service SDK for Android

Tags: salesforce-sdk-android

I am getting the below error when selecting build variants in example give in github

https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-Android/tree/master/Examples/SnapinsSDKExample

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@javaImplDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.salesforce.service:servicesdk:224.0.0

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please could you take a minute to read https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question with more complete information? For me, what you have here doesn't provide enough of your LWC component's detail in order to help you